# How to flip query results in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to select multiple rows from one row in a source sheet based on another column in the source sheet. E.g.:

```
Name   Start                  Add
Bob    2012-01-01 01:01:00    10:00:00
Tim    2020-01-01 01:01:00    04:00:00
```

And what I am looking for in the output is something like:

```
Bob                    Tim
2012-01-01 11:01:00    2020-01-01 05:01:00
2012-01-01 21:01:00    2020-01-01 10:01:00
2012-01-02 07:01:00    2020-01-01 15:01:00
...
```

I'm not sure how to do this, if it's possible... I've been working on getting the time modification done (which also isn't intuitive) but I realized I also don't know how to repeat and pivot the results.

Comment: TRANSPOSE() is sort of what I'm looking for, but I want multiple values for each input row...

Comment: Are you looking for a single function formula or are you open to have multiple functions in your formula? Please add a link to a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link.

Answer (score 0):

In [Test_Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CZ94ADNATn8H7_3dwIP2nxVMXmGZw7NzbuUWG3BFAaw/edit#gid=771685629) You'll find following formula for each name

```
={transpose(A2:B2);arrayformula(SEQUENCE(D2,1,1,1)*C2+B2)}
```

Tried to make it for whole array, but SEQUENCE failed me to return array.